# Postgres service is not starting

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6

After reinstalling the postgreSQL, postgres service is not starting.

I'm installing postgreSQL. It's Data folder gets created under "ProgramData" folder. During uninstall of PostgreSQL, I'm keeping Data folder as it is but removing postmaster.pid. When I'm doing reinstall of postgres, postmaster.pid is not available but it's gets created with reinstallation of PostgreSQL. But after reinstallation, postgres service is not starting and giving the following error :

[image]

Is anyone has any idea why this happening?

Comment: Look into the PostgreSQL log.

Comment: What do you mean, are you reinstalling Postgresql across the existing install? Have you dumped the databases?

Comment: @Slumdog Yes, I have dumped the DB, took a backup of Postgres Data folder before uninstallation of Postgres. And then installing it again.

Comment: ok you should be fine if you have a dump_all. Are you on Windows? You probably have a path setting that is still seeing your old install? Are you keeping your data folder for your .conf files? Perhaps move the folder away somewhere else. After uninstall I suggest you check and remove any folders that might remain. As a note you can install Postgresql almost in any folder, should be fine. Before uninstall make sure you stop the Postgresql service otherwise it may not cleanly uninstall